# Used one power adapter for 4 devices

Tags: power, adapter

Power four circuits from one adapter an output of the adapter is 12v, 3A.

Should I use the Extention cables like the daisy chain, Should I make some connection in series after the adapter to get 4 outputs.

If I applied the following steps there will be no voltage drop on 4 of the circuits?

Answer (score 1):

If all your 4 devices require 12V power source, and total combined current consumption will not exceed capability of your adapter (3A), then you can use this power adapter to power all 4 devices at the same time.

There will be always some voltage drop in any cable. It just depends on what voltage drop you (or your devices) will accept.

If you want to daisy chain power cable, of course the device which is most distant from power source will have the highest voltage drop. But it all depends on thickness of cables. The voltage drop could be negligible.

Comment: How can I get rid of the voltage drop on any of the device? What should be the thickness required for the daisy chain cable that there should be no drop voltage?

Comment: It's not possible to have no voltage drop. You can make it very small by using thick wires. Rule of thumb for low voltages (12V and such): >0.1mm² cross section per m cable length and ampere current.

Comment: @Awaiskhan zero voltage drop is possible only in one case: you'll invent power cable with zero resistance (that is impossible). We all live in real world. Even your power source won't give you exactly 12.00000V. Say your power source will have tolerance +-1%, it means that voltage of your power source will be between 11.88V and 12.12V. So it is not very important if you will have voltage drop like 0.05V in the wires, right?

Comment: @Chupacabras Yes if we have some voltage drop on the cables is fine, I'm searching for an option which is more reliable and efficient for me to use for the circuit, the circuit are using 5v not 12v.

Comment: @Awaiskhan you mentioned 12V in your question, not 5V. But it doesn't change the point of my answer.

Comment: @Chupacabras sorry for it, the adapter output is 12v but on the circuit I used 5v not 12v

Comment: @Awaiskhan it doesn't matter, voltage drop depends on the volume of current, not voltage.

Comment: If you supply a 5v circuit with 12v, either you destroy the circuit, or the circuit have a regulator which lowers the 12v to 5v. In the latter case the regulator compensates for whatever voltage drop you have. But you waste some power in the regulator.

Comment: @Lenne of course, but the question was about voltage drop, not another circuitry. He did not ask whether he can use 12V and supply it directly to 5V devices or not. That is another story.

Comment: I have another question as I can't make another post for 3 days so I'm posting it in here, IM using a honey well sensor Board Mount,  I want to know that can I used it without the pull-up resistor? Another thing if I should use pull-up resistor which pins should I attached and what should be the values of the resistor? 2.2 k and 4.7k, I will be testing it with the Arduino. @Chupacabras

Comment: @Chupacabras "the adapter output is 12v but on the circuit I used 5v". I may have misunderstood this. That's not hard...